# How to select min date a not max date

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I'm trying to select the minimum and NOT the maximun date in a table. Instead of the maximun date I want to select the date of the fourth event. Any advice?

| User | Event | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 1 | 2021-06-06 |
| xyz | 2 | 2021-06-26 |
| xyz | 3 | 2021-07-30 |
| xyz | 4 | 2022-01-10 |
| xyz | 5 | 2022-02-14 |
| xyz | 6 | 2022-02-21 |

I was trying something like this:

```
select user, min(date), max(date) from table
where event <= 4
group by user
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So, you want the minimum date among ALL the rows, and the specific date for event 4?  That really should be two separate queries.  It can be done in one, but that's confusing.

Comment: Yes, my code is working but would like to know another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative to your current solution uses aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    "user",
    MIN(date) AS min_date,
    MIN(date) FILTER (WHERE event = 4) AS fourth_date
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY "user";
```

For a more general solution, we can use `RANK()` along with a pivot query:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "user" ORDER BY date) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    "user",
    MAX(date) FILTER (WHERE rnk = 1) AS min_date,
    MAX(date) FILTER (WHERE rnk = 4) AS fourth_date
FROM cte
GROUP BY "user";
```

Depending on the ties behavior you want, using `DENSE_RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()` might make sense.

Comment: I don't think they wanted the 4th event in order by date, I think they wanted the row where event == 4.  Perhaps I misinterpreted.

Comment: Assuming events would always be numbered starting at 1 for every user, my answer would still be valid.

Comment: Thanks Tim. One last thing, how do you filter to only select users that have 4 or more events?

Comment: @droscar Add `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4` or maybe `COUNT(DISTINCT event) >= 4` to the end of my first query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query for the part not affected by the WHERE.

```
SELECT user, date, (SELECT MIN(date) FROM one) 
FROM one 
WHERE event=4;
```